# Differences between code in the timeline and using a Document Class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I had some code directly in the timeline that accessed/modified properties of some movie clips. 
I then did the proper thing and moved the code to a Document class. I put the code that was formerly in the timeline into the document class constructor.

The issue I'm having is that if I access the movie clip properties "too soon" it reports that they are null. If I put the code in a timer event callback for half a second or so, or put an addFrameScript call with a frame of around 8 or higher, the movie clip references are valid and it all works.

So for some reason by the time the code in the timeline gets called all of the movie clip instances are valid. However, when inside of a document class constructor, they are not. I've tried using the ENTER_FRAME event callback but the movieclips still aren't ready.

The code is supposed to change some movie clip properties based on some loaderinfo parameters, so I do kind of need to set those properties before anything starts animating.

Answer (score 3):

> So for some reason by the time the code in the timeline gets called all of the movie clip instances are valid. However, when inside of a document class constructor, they are not.

That's right.  The constructor is called before the main movieclip ("the Timeline") is added to the stage.  The timeline is an object that inherits `flash.display.MovieClip`, and it has to be instantiated before it can appear anywhere.  This also happens when you don't assign a document class, by the way.

To make sure you access properties that have been properly initialized (such as objects you have placed on the stage in the IDE), move the related code into an event handler and listen for [Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/Event.html#ADDED_TO_STAGE).

Comment: Ah, thanks! I managed to find a solution. When I add Event.ADDED and Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE event handlers to the document class constructor, I found that the first 2 calls made were ADDED, then ADDED_TO_STAGE for the document class. After that, it looks like an ADDED event is fired for every object that was placed on the stage. It seems like when the movieclips I'm trying to manipulate are ADDED, I can then modify them in the document class code.

Comment: @Guts `Event.ADDED` fires every time that a `DisplayObject` is *added* to a `DisplayObjectContainer`. `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` is fired when a `DisplayObject` is *added to the stage*, directly or indirectly, by been *added* in some `DisplayObjectContainer` that will be (or already is) *added* to the stage.